# When returning a reference gcc adds 0x30 to %eax

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, gcc, disassembly

I have a function and call it:

```
Class1& Class2::get()
{
   return *m_ptr;
}

Class1& c = m_class2->get();
```

m_ptr is a custom smart pointer and I can see in debugger that m_ptr.m_p is 0, also I can see inside its operator T* that it really returns 0. However address of c (&c) is not NULL, it is 0x30! What I see in disassembly:

```
13059       return *m_ptr;
eaabbc7e:   mov 0x8(%ebp),%eax
eaabbc81:   add $0xb4,%eax
eaabbc86:   mov %eax,(%esp)
eaabbc89:   call 0xea9ce4c0  <operator T*>
eaabbc8e:   add $0x30,%eax
13060     }
```

Just before line add $0x30,%eax I can see that %eax is 0, that is operator correctly returned NULL.

Why the line to add 0x30 is here???

Comment: Is this question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368647/gcc-x64-stack-manipulation

Comment: Well I don't know, I'm not _that_ big expert in asm.

Comment: I do not deference it. That's not even my code, but it checks if (&c != NULL) and &c != NULL.

Comment: Without seeing the smart pointer's dereference operator, there's no way to tell whether that's expected or not. Either way, you mustn't dereference a null pointer, even if you're just doing it to initialise a reference.

Comment: @queen3: You do dereference it, assuming that's what the `operator*()` in `*m_ptr` does.

Comment: Are you using multiple inheritance ?

Comment: That's not operator*(), it is operator T*: T* m_p; operator T*() const { return m_p; }. and this is what is returned as Class2& as far as I understand.

Comment: Multiple inheritance only for Class2.

Comment: @queen3: Then I think that's the answer. If the smart pointer points to a base class of `Class2` rather than `Class2` itself, then the conversion to `Class2*` (which is needed before dereferencing it to give your `Class2&`) will require adding an offset to the pointer. Obviously this is not valid if the pointer is null.

Comment: Mike, can you make your comment an answer? ;-) This is damn correct!

Comment: It would have been nicer if you had posted a complete minimal example that people could compile and see for themselves. Since we dont know what m_ptr is, we cant reason about what would be correct, or why the compiler would do it like that way.

Comment: Actually multiple inheritance is for the m_ptr real object, which is the casted to Class1 and thus 0x30, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there's not enough information to answer, your comments hint that `Class2` involves multiple inheritance, and I will hazard a guess that the template parameter `T` a derived class, not `Class2` itself.

So `operator T*` returns a pointer to this derived class. In order to dereference it to give `Class2&`, it must be converted to `Class2*`, which may involve adding an offset to the pointer, depending on how the compiler lays out the base class sub-objects within the object.

Obviously this is only valid if the pointer is not null; that's one reason why you must never dereference a null pointer even if you're only using the result to initialise a reference.

If the function returned `Class2*`, then you would get a null pointer as expected; that conversion is required to convert null to null. In your case, since you're invoking undefined behaviour in that case by dereferencing the pointer, there's no need for the compiler to check for null before performing the conversion.

Comment: Actually that was opposite - template parameter T is superclass, while Class2 is it's base, but still this must be the answer!

Comment: @queen3: Yes, that makes more sense than my guess.

Comment: What's interesting is that this code (which is being ported to Linux) seems to work under Windows. I suppose MS always checks for NULL, even for references.